# Maven can't access/transfer from the central repository (or local one apparently)

Tags: maven

When I try to to run most maven commands I get this error or something very similar

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom: Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]
```

This originally happened while using eclipse, using normal cmd gives the same error (and on a blank new project too).

I have tried deleting my .m2 folder, forcing it to update snapshots and manually downloading the plugins from my browser. Most answers to this problem are about proxy problems, but I am *not* using a proxy.

Comment: The problem is: `Received fatal alert: protocol_version` which Java version do you use?

Comment: I was told that to make bukkit plugins (minecraft) I needed java 1.7, I changed it and that's what was giving problems. Thanks a lot